# How to use SqlCommand and DataAdapter in order to manipulate SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

1. I create table called `Department` with 2 columns `Department ID` which is auto increment and `Department Name`
2. I create `Navigate_Department()` in order to walk through the department rows

   ```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
   DataSet Dep_ds;
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter Dep_da;
   int Dep_MaxRows = 0;
   int Dep_inc = 0;

   private void ILS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
      con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\ILS_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
      con.Open();

      Dep_ds = new DataSet();
      string sql2 = "select * from Department order by DepartmentID";
      Dep_da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql2, con);
      Dep_da.Fill(Dep_ds, "Department");
      Navigate_Department();
      Dep_MaxRows = Dep_ds.Tables["Department"].Rows.Count;
   }

   private void Navigate_Department() 
   {
       DataRow dRow = Dep_ds.Tables["Department"].Rows[Dep_inc];

       Dep_ID.Text =dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
       Dep_Name.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString(); 
   }

   private void Move_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (Dep_inc != Dep_MaxRows-1)
       {
           Dep_inc++;
           Navigate_Department();
        }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("No More Records");
       }
   }

   private void Move_back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (Dep_inc > 0)
       {
           Dep_inc--;
           Navigate_Department();
        }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("First Record");
       }
   }

   private void Dep_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Dep_ID.Clear();
       Dep_Name.Clear();
   }

   private void Dep_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           SqlCommand insCmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.Department (DepartmentName) values ('" + Dep_Name.Text + "')", con);
           Dep_da.InsertCommand = insCmd;

           Dep_MaxRows = Dep_MaxRows + 1;
           Dep_inc = Dep_MaxRows - 1;
           Dep_Max.Text = Dep_MaxRows.ToString();
           Dep_Current.Text = (Dep_MaxRows).ToString();
       }
       catch (Exception exceptionObject)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.Message);
       }
   ```

The problem is:

After I click clear button, I insert the department name into `Dep_Name` textbox then click add button. The name that I inserted didn’t get saved in the database, and if I click move back then move next in order to see what I inserted, I get a `Index out of range` exception in the   `Navigate_Department()` method.

So did I make any mistake?

Comment: Parametrize your SQL queries.  Don't append text box values into SQL strings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the name you're inserting isn't saved in the database is because you never execute the insert command.  Add:

```
int ret = Dep_da.Update(Dep_ds);

after the

Dep_da.InsertCommand = insCmd;
```

The variable ret will contain the number of rows successfully updated (inserted) - which in your case should be 1.

To add to what @N. Warfield wrote, if you simply append raw data into your SQL string that a user (or another system, for that matter) provides, you leave yourself wide-open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: this error appear when I execute the program 
"Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'."

Comment: Try specifying the table name in the Update method - i.e. Dep_da.Update(Dep_ds, "Department");

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create the insert statement like this you should use the data adapter with an insert command, add a new DataRow instance to the table then use the data adapter to execute the update.

Alternatively you could execute the insert command within Dep_Add_Click by replacing the call to "Dep_da.InsertCommand = insCmd" with "insCmd.ExecuteNonQuery", however this would mean that you would need to re-run the select statement and repopulate the dataset from the database to get the data from the database into the dataset.