# The new row added didn’t save into underlying database using C# and SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataadapter

I am trying this code to add new row to database, the new row is saved but when I close the program down, reopen it, the row has disappeared.

```
private void Dep_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(Dep_da);

       DataRow dRow = Dep_ds.Tables["Department"].NewRow();
       dRow[1] = Dep_Name.Text;
       Dep_ds.Tables["Department"].Rows.Add(dRow);

       Dep_MaxRows = Dep_MaxRows + 1;
       Dep_inc = Dep_MaxRows - 1;

       Dep_da.Update(Dep_ds,"Department");
   }
   catch (Exception exceptionObject)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.Message);
   }
```

So I hope someone can help me

Comment: You don't see any error messages or anything?

Comment: No there is no any message appear

Comment: Look in your solution and your folders. Is this for an Attached Db?  Those are copied (overwrite) to the bin folder before use.

Comment: The message appear only when I add a repetitive record into a unique Column

Comment: The program retrieve all the  record I inserted in sql server good but when I add any record in c # the record didn’t appear again when I restart the visual studio

Comment: OK 2 comments contradicting each other here:  1: "No there is no any message appear" and 2: "The message appear only ..." . So what is it please?  Add stacktraces and exact error messages.

Comment: Can you **plase show us** the connection string you're using for your database???

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much context information, so this is a bit of a guess...

If you are doing this from inside Visual Studio, and are writing to a local (attached) database, then every time you execute the program, the local db is being copied from your project to your bin folder, so you are starting each execution with the same copy of the database, overwriting the db that was modified in the last execution.

You should be able to test if this is the case by running your exe from explorer or the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558711/how-to-use-sql-command-and-data-adaptor-in-order-to-manipulate-database-using-sql/6559392#6559392), though with slightly different code.

I gave an answer for you on your previous question - which is to use the SqlDataAdapter.Update command.  You're doing that here, but you didn't post the rest of your code so I don't know if you changed anything.

Comment: I am sorry, I just little bit confused

Comment: I found another code , it didn’t appears the ‘Index out of range’ expiation, but it is also doesn’t save the new record inserted into underlying Database

Comment: Did you change anything else in your code, or just the Dep_Add_Click method?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably call DataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges() method?